# file.getName() cannot find symbol for method getName() (using Gradle and Javalin)

Tags: gradle, fileutils, javalin

When i try to run this code:

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getContent(), new File("upload/" + file.getName()));
```

I get this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getName()
location: variable file of type UploadedFile
```

I have already imported these:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

I'm working with Gradle and I have already added to the dependencies in build.gradle.kts this one:

```
 implementation(group= "commons-io", name= "commons-io", version= "2.5")
```

so the build.gradle.kts file builds correctly.

What else should I import? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Javalin's [`UploadedFile`](https://github.com/tipsy/javalin/blob/97ad617a334c1eb68d7512d85a43961f4bb39276/javalin/src/main/java/io/javalin/http/UploadedFile.kt#L21) has no property named `name`. However, it has `filename`, so this may work (not tested):

```
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getContent(), new File("upload/" + file.getFilename()));
```